# check recursevely if there git checked out files

Tags: git, powershell, cmd

I've all my projects in a folder called c:\Projects. They're all git projects hosted on Bitbucket, I wish to traverse all those folders and check if there're modified files I need to push. Is there a way I can do this via PowerShell / cmd line?

Thanks

Comment: "*…GitHub projects hosted on Bitbucket.*" :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use simple script:

```
$directory = "C:\users\turek\source\my_git_repos";
dir $directory -Directory | ForEach-Object { 
    cd $_.FullName;
    git status; 
};
```

Or, more sophisticated version, which does not goes into directories, which are not git repositories:

```
$directory = "C:\users\turek\source\my_git_repos";
# gets all subdirectories and loops through them
dir $directory -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # if the directory is git repo, then check the status
    if ( Test-Path -Path "$($_.FullName)\.git" ) {
        # switches directory
        cd $_.FullName;
        # gets GIT repo status 
        git status; 
    }
};
```